# How to modify a given line of the terminal?

Tags: terminal, io-redirection, output

Literally, I want to print to any displayed line on the terminal. I remember we've learned this in university, but was ages ago.
Is there a command for this?

Like this:

`___________             ___________
|blah       |           |blah       |
|bla        |           |blah       |
|randomtext |           |blah       |
|xy         |  ----->   |blah       |
|hjkl       |           |blah       |
|prompt>    |           |prompt>    |
|___________|           |___________|`

Comment: You're looking to overwrite text that has already been displayed?

Comment: Exactly, overwrite any alredy displayed character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the cursor to any X,Y co-ordinate with the `tput cup` command

eg

```
tput cup 10 3
```

will take you to line 10, column 3  (co-ordinates start at 0,0 as the top-left)

so a simple script such as

```
clear
echo line 1
echo line 2
echo line 3
tput cup 1 5
echo another line
tput cup 10 0
```

will result in output similar to

```
line 1
line another line
line 3








$
```

(where the `$` is your prompt).

The first `tput` command moves the cursor back up to the earlier line allowing the `echo` to overwrite what was already there.

Answer (score 1):

There exist [xterm control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) that offer a variety of ways to mangle the terminal display, typically via the `tput(1)` command or the `curses` library. Or at the risk of portability problems, you can issue the escape sequences directly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
tput sc
for i in {1..10}; do
    echo -ne "\x1b[${i};${i}H\x1bKblah"
done
tput rc
```

The terminal can also be put into raw mode and the cursor position then read, a good read might be the [linenoise library](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise) to see how this is done.